# Custom Post Types and Categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy

For the life of me I cannot seem to get categories to come into existence with my custom post type. I've added the following — simple — code to the bottom of my theme's `functions.php` file, yet see no categories in my custom post from the admin side.

```
register_post_type("customy", array(
    'label' => 'Customy',
    'description' => 'Custom stuff for this site.',
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
    'taxonomies' => array('category')
));
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'customy');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that although `register_post_type()` will add the new `post_type` immediately, it seems as though you need to bind up the logic into a function, and add it to the `init` action for the categories taxonomy to be associated with the `post_type`. A working example follows:

```
function add_articles_post_type() {
  register_post_type("article", array(
    'label' => 'Article',
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','revisions')
  ));
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'article');
}
add_action('init', 'add_articles_post_type');
```